# Calculation of elastic constants - when do we need to account for Poisson?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, crystals, continuum-mechanics, molecular-dynamics, density-functional-theory

I try to calculate the elastic constant tensor for some organic molecular crystals.
There are plenty of accounts in the literature where people do that, using atomic
resolution models and DFT, EAM, or classical empirical force fields. A popular
way of getting the result from that is by deforming/shearing the unit (or super)
cell in a given direction and then use the calculated stress tensor to make a
stress strain diagram, and from that calculate the elastic constants.
This is straight forward enough, but there is one technical detail that I still
have to see anybody discussing:
When applying a deformation (compression, or shear) then people appear to disregard
the fact that usually deformation in one direction also entails a deformation
in the other directions (as measured by the Poisson ratio), i.e. they deform their
model/box in a way shown in panels A and B in the attached figure, probably
because one cannot account for deformations in the other directions, since the
Poisson ratio is ususally not known ahead of the actual calculation, or because
generating the deformed structure is easier that way.
However, when trying to reproduce experimental numbers, obviously using geometries
as shown in panels C and D would be more appropriate.

[image]

so here's my question: Does this matter - perhaps if we look at small deformations
well inside the elastic regime, the difference is negligible? Or do people actually
use geometries as shown in panels C and D, and just don't mention it? If so,
how can I do that without knowing the Poisson ration ahead of my calculation,
unless I use a tedious iterative procedure?

I hope I managed to make my question clear!

Thanks for any answers!
regards,
Michael

Answer (score 2):

The difference can NOT be ignored, even for an isotropic material (and I would guess your organic crystals are not isotropic, which makes things more complicated).

Assuming your pictures *are* of an isotropic material, if you apply equal and opposite loads normal to the surface and with no other restraints, you will change the shape of the material as in picture C. You can measure the changes in length and width, and calculate Young's modulus and Poisson's ratio directly from the two measurements. (There will also be a change in thickness, but for an isotropic material that doesn't give any new information about the material properties).

On the other hand if you want the deformed shape to be like picture A, you also need to apply loads to *all four sides* of the material, not just the two loads that you show in the picture. Again, you can calculate $E$ and $\nu$ directly from the two applied loads.

Pictures B and D are not physically realistic, because if the loads as shown would act as a couple and cause rigid body *rotation* of the material. If that is prevented in some way, the restraints will be applying additional loads which create and equal and opposite couple.

Of course in a computer model you don't have any practical problems imposing any boundary conditions you like, but if you consider *all* the forces on the structure caused by the boundary conditions, you have enough information to find all the material properties.

For more information about the simplest case, look up "plane stress" and "plane strain" in any textbook on strength of materials (for a simple introduction) or continuum mechanics (for a more complete mathematical treatment).

Note that to measure material properties, the method of "applying forces and measuring the deformation" is often not used for practical reasons. A better method is often to measure the mode shapes and frequencies of several different vibration modes of a test piece. The only physical properties you need to measure are then the undeformed shape of the test specimen, and its density, both of which are easy to measure accurately.

Comment: thanks alephzero, for your elaborate answer! ... I guess what I failed to mention is that the calculations I refer to typically use periodic boundary conditions, so, in fact we measure the stress in an infinitely large deformed sample with no surfaces, and for that we determine the full stress tensor - can it be that the "loads on all four sides" you mention are implicitly accounted for in this stress tensor? ... also, do you, by any chance, have any references for the method you mention in your last paragraph? (measuring mode shapes).

Answer (score 0):

The elasticity parameters reduces to modulus of elasticity $E$ and Poisson coeficient $\nu$ only for isotropic materials.

In this case for example:

$\sigma_{xx}=(\lambda + 2\mu)\epsilon_{xx} + \lambda\epsilon_{yy}+\lambda*\epsilon_{zz}$
$\sigma_{xy}= 2\mu\epsilon_{xy}$

where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are the Lamé constants of the material, ($E$ and $\nu$ can be expressed as a function of them).

So, measuring the principal strains with a strain gage, and the stresses with a load cell, it is enough two tests, one of them uniaxial, to determine the parameters.

But for a totally anisotropic material, there are 21 elastic parameters, and many different tests are certainly necessary .